# My ExecuteNonQuery returns -1 even though 4 rows are affected

Tags: c#, sql, executenonquery

When I run the query against the database, I get `(4 row(s) affected)`.

When I run it through C#, I get `-1` as the return value.

This is my code:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT name FROM stock";

int x = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Why do I get -1?

Comment: Why do you use ExecuteNonQuery to run a query?

Comment: It's not an `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE`, so no rows have been *affected* (SSMS's use of the word "affected" is different than `ExecuteNonQuery`'s). But also, calling `ExecuteNonQuery` with a `SELECT` doesn't make sense because it *is* a query.

Comment: @AKX honestly idk lol im new to using sql and i thought i will return the amount of rows that exist under the collum. is there a better way?

Comment: Yes. Call ExecuteReader(), or use an SqlDataAdapter to Fill() a DataTable.